# Java дженерики и вилдкарды

Tags: java, generics, wildcards

Кто-нибудь, объясните мне следующее поведение. Есть класс

```
public class ClassMap<T> extends LinkedHashMap<Class<? extends T>, T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void put(T item) {
        put((Class<? extends T>) item.getClass(), item);
    }
}
```

есть два объекта этого класса

```
private ClassMap<ServerSchedule> serverTasks = new ClassMap<ServerSchedule>() {
    {
        put(...);
        put(...);
        put(...);
        put(...);
    }
};

private ClassMap<SensorIdSchedule> sensorTasks= new ClassMap<SensorIdSchedule>() {
    {
        put(...);
        put(...);
        put(...);
        put(...);
    }
};
```

Есть методы

```
public final Single<SyncCondition<ServerSchedule>> syncCondition() {
    return // Something
}
```

в ServerSchedule

и

```
public final Single<SyncCondition<? extends SensorIdSchedule>> syncCondition(String sensorId) {
    this.sensorId = sensorId;
    return syncCondition();
}

public abstract Single<SyncCondition<? extends SensorIdSchedule>> syncCondition();
```

в SensorIdSchedule

Вопрос же в следующем. Почему на вызов

```
List<SyncCondition<? extends SensorIdSchedule>> sensorConditions =
                            ListUtil.map(sensorTasks.keySet(), sClass -> sensorTasks.get(sClass).syncCondition(sensorId).blockingGet());
```

Компилятор не ругается, а на вызов

```
List<SyncCondition<? extends ServerSchedule>> serverConditions =
                            ListUtil.map(serverTasks.keySet(), sClass -> serverTasks.get(sClass).syncCondition().blockingGet());
```

ругается ещё как. Говорит что не `List<SyncCondition<? extends ServerSchedule>>` должен получаться, а `List<Object>`. Но для двух аследников `Schedule` всё сделано одинаково, в чем же разница?

PS Если это не очень понятно, то ListUtil.map() простой метод, который использует магию стримов, но скрывает ее реализацию:

```
public static <T, E> List<E> map(Collection<T> list, Function<? super T, ? extends E> function) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(list)
            .map(function)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**UPDATED**

Похоже дело в том, что `ServerSchedule` параметризован, добавил непараметризованную прослойку между Schedule и SensorSchedule (какой является и SensorIdSchedule) и компиятор перестал ругаться

```
public abstract class JustSchedule extends Schedule {

    public JustSchedule(Context context, HealbeClient healbeClient, long delay) {
        super(context, healbeClient, delay);
    }

    public abstract Single<SyncCondition<? extends JustSchedule>> syncCondition();
}
```

Comment: Врод можно было просто сделать `List<SyncCondition<? extends ServerSchedule>> serverConditions =
                            (List<SyncCondition<? extends ServerSchedule>>) ListUtil.map(serverTasks.keySet(), sClass -> serverTasks.get(sClass).syncCondition().blockingGet());` Если конечно типы правильные )

Comment: Проверять уже не буду, но наверное сработало бы. Тут скорее интереснее почему с SensorIdSchedule все работает без приведения типов, а для ServerSchedule это приведение нужно. Подозреваю, что дело в том, что ServerSchedule сам параметризированный, но из метода то я его возвращаю без параметров, значит по хорошему оно должно работать.